# How to capture video in android with audio muted via default INTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture

I want to capture video by simply opening default video recorder but sound must be disabled while capturing. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
 startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_VIDEO_CAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` protocol that affects audio. You are welcome to use `AudioManager` and change audio settings yourself, but the third-party app that you are launching is also welcome to change the audio settings, and there is nothing that you can do about that.

The only way to ensure that the audio settings are what you want is to record the video yourself with a `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: how can i mute the audio during video capture with `MediaRecoder`... if i skip initializing `mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource` app crashes.

Comment: @Ryderz: "how can i mute the audio during video capture" -- use `AudioManager` and change the volume level. If by "mute the audio" you mean "prevent the recording from picking up audio", I am not aware that this is possible, but you should be able to post-process the video to remove the audio track.

Comment: thnxs for the reponse .. is there any library by which i can do that ? i have searched alot but no result.

Comment: @Ryderz: "is there any library by which i can do that ?" -- I am not sure what "that" is. If "that" is remove the audio track from a video, if you are uploading your video to a server, I would do the work there, as you have more power and flexibility. Otherwise, see if one of the `ffmpeg` ports for Android can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with CommonsWare answer it is all depending upon the third party application to accept the parameters and for now there is no third party application which is supporting this tag.

As much as I know there is no third party video recording application which is supporting that mute audio tag. you can override audio manager services and mute recording volume and start video recording Intent but there is no guarantee that third party application will not unmute audio. Another way around implement your own video recording Interface using Surface view or capture video and use any library to mute audio from it.

Comment: I tried to mute the system volume by- 
`((AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,true);`
but on accessing the video from server i can see sound with it

Comment: That we were discussing about if third party application unmute the mic volume than you can't do anything in this scenario, please try implement own Surface view to record video or extract and remove audio from captured video once it received in your application onActivityResult

Comment: can you please share any link by which i can `extract and remove audio from captured video once it received in your application onActivityResult`

Comment: I am not sure but this thread is looking useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598771/android-strip-audio-from-video